# Need to choose the best solution to store my ios Data

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have 1 megabytes(text) ( user input) to store in my iOS application. The user answers for questions (exam questions). My goal is to store all the answers in my application, and ask for him later, for example "give me all the good answers witch user "a" have answered,....) witch the best choice to store this informations? `SQLite` ? `property list` ( can i user xpath with `property list` ??), core data ? thanks

Comment: My suggestion would be sqlite.

Comment: why sqlite ? and not Core data , or plist ?

Comment: I think, what you know/like most of all, that would be the best. Even `const char*` :)

Comment: I haven't work more on core data or p list hence I am not comfortable with that but if you use sq-lite then you can create table for specific category questions or answers. you can set tag in table for answers that will be useful when you retrieved specific answers.

Comment: Does the user really need to type a whole megabyte worth of test answers?

Comment: Yes. You think that core data is the best choice ?

Comment: CoreData is great because, if for any reason you change the structure of your database, CoreData has a system that allows to merge your modification easily. However, CoreData is longer/harder to implement that a simple SQLite database. In fact, there is no best choice, it depends on the time you have (or want to spend) on this app and what do you prefer and/or master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is the standard for data storage such as this in iOS.

- [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), a really useful lib for Core Data
  simplification